# How to seed dynamic data in Entity Framework configuration

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have the following extension method for seeding the data:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
   public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      //Key is GUID type and automatically generated on insert
      modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().Property(x => x.Key).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()"); 

      modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().HasData(
        new Author
        {
            FirstName = "William",
            LastName = "Shakespeare"
        });   
    }
  }
```

Now, the generated key shall be passed as value to other table seed data.

How do I get `AuthorId` for below statements?

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasData(
        new Book { BookId = 1, AuthorId = ?, Title = "Hamlet" },
        new Book { BookId = 2, AuthorId = ?, Title = "King Lear" },
        new Book { BookId = 3, AuthorId = ?, Title = "Othello" }
    );
```

Comment: Please take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63243793/862795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HasData` enables `IDENTITY_INSERT`. I have checked it debugging [DataSeeding](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/Modeling/DataSeeding) project:

```
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns] 
     WHERE [name] IN (N'BlogId', N'Url') AND 
           [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Blogs]'))
          SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Blogs] ON;       #<--- here
      INSERT INTO [Blogs] ([BlogId], [Url])

      VALUES (1, N'http://sample.com');

      IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns] 
                 WHERE [name] IN (N'BlogId', N'Url') AND 
                       [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Blogs]'))
          SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Blogs] OFF;      #<--- here
```

Then, for your data, the easy way is to inform PK's:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().HasData(
    new Author
    {   Id = 1,     //#<--- here
        FirstName = "William",
        LastName = "Shakespeare"
    });  

  ...

  modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasData(
    new Book { BookId = 1, AuthorId = 1, #<--- here
               Title = "Hamlet" },
```

Quoting [Data Seeding docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding).

> The primary key value needs to be specified even if it's usually generated by the database. It will be used to detect data changes between migrations.

Comment: I did not get you. Is it a solution?! how do I implement it?

Comment: Including PK values on seed data.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. PK is dynamically generated! Once generated it must pass to child tables.

Comment: If the keys are generated using IDENTITY, as Dani already mentioned, you can use fixed values and EF Core will take care of inserting them using IDENTITY_INSERT. If you don't want to use fixed values, then the model-based data seeding feature isn't the right solution. To quote the documentation again: > ...this feature is most useful for static data that's not expected to change outside of migrations and does not depend on anything else in the database...